# Custom SeekBarPreference setProgress from a different class?

Tags: java, android, view, preference

Hello I am wondering how to use the following method `findViewById(int id)` inside a class that extends `Preference` that has a method defined called `setProgress(int progress)` which uses the method `findViewById` so that way in another class that extends `PreferenceActivity` I could use the method `setProgress(int progress)`. So since the method `findViewById` is defined in the class `android.view.View` how am I suppose to use the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to pass either a specific View or an Activity to the function, or if the setProgress function isn't static, store the View or Activity in a variable inside the class somehow.

Comment: When you say pass the `activity`  do you mean its `context`?

Comment: No, context objects don't have the method `findViewById`

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer on this website:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/163541/SeekBar-Preference

You could use

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) setContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_slider, null);
```

and then you can find view by id using

```
mSeekBar = (SeekBar) view.findViewById(R.id.seek_bar);
```